# R: How to obtain elements from vectors, if the the vectors form part of a list?

Tags: r

I have two lists:

```
myList1 <- list(c("","VNW","SPEC","N","BW" ), c("","WW","N","SPEC","ADJ"),c( "","WW","N"), c("","WW","N"), c("","ADJ","N","WW"), c( "","ADJ","N"))

myList2 <- list(c( "","125141","44","4945","3"), c("","114146","77","19","3"), c("","4359","695"), c("","1372","623"), c("","209","71","1"), c( "","33","3"))
```

I also have indices in either of two forms:

```
MyNIndices <- c(4,3,3,3,3,3)
```

or

```
MyNIndices <- list (4,3,3,3,3,3)
```

MyNIndices reflect which element on each of the vectors in MyList1 does "N" occur at?

Now, I want to be able to index into the same indices on myList2 so that I can get the value corresponding to N. So, I want as output

```
MyFinalValues <- c(4945, 77, 695, 623, 71, 3)
```

OR

```
MyFinalValues <- list(4945, 77, 695, 623, 71, 3)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In tidyverse you can

```
library(purrr)
map2(myList2,MyNIndices, `[[`)
```

or, if you want a numeric vector back

```
map2_chr(myList2,MyNIndices, `[[`) %>% 
    as.numeric()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
MyFinalValues <- mapply(function(x,i) x[i],x=myList2, i=MyNIndices)
if(is.list(MyNIndices)) MyFinalValues=list(MyFinalValues)
```